# Binary Indexed Tree (Fenwick Tree) - about updating

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, fenwick-tree

I've recently learned the [Fenwick Tree (Binary Indexed Tree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) data structure.

When querying , I can understand why to subtract (idx & -idx).
However, I can't really understand why to add (idx & -idx) when updating a value.

In other words, I know we have to update all intervals which will be affected by updating some single element x , and I know that BIT[x] is the first to be updated , but can't understand why the next index to be updated is BIT[x + (x & -x)]

Thanks.

Comment: Draw out a simple example on paper

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good explanation: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees

The key idea is that if f(i) is the frequency at index i, then t(i) is the cumulative frequency for all (i - (r - 1)) .. i where r is the least set bit in i.  You can calculate r as r = i & -i.

[EDIT: above I had incorrectly written (r - 1) as (2^r - 1).]

For example, if i = 12 = 1100_2, then r = 100_2 and t(i) = f(1001_2) + f(1010_2) + f(1011_2) + f(1100_2) = f(9) + f(10) + f(11) + f(12).

When calculating the cumulative frequency from 0 .. i, you essentially sum the t values at i, i with its least set bit removed, i with its least two set bits removed, ... and so forth until we run out of bits.

For example, if i = 12 = 1100_2, then we want t(1100_2) + t(1000_2).

Consequently, if you change the value at f(i), you must change all the affected t values.  These are t(i), t(i + r), 2t(i + r), 4t(i + r), ... and so forth until we exceed the last index.  These are precisely the affected t values we would examine for any cumulative frequency calculation for index j >= i.

[EDIT: fixed the 'affected t values' sequence in the last paragraph in response to a correction by j_random_hacker.]

Comment: "These are t(i), t(i + r), t(i + 2r), t(i + 4r)" isn't quite right -- after each time you add the lowest-order 1 bit, you need to start afresh, which can make the later jumps larger when there are carries.  E.g. look at the totals that include 7 in image 1.3 of your link, namely 7, 8, 16.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: you're quite right -- well spotted!  I've edited my explanation accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not quite right! I don't think there's necessarily a nice closed-form expression for it, it's easiest to describe (and implement!) recursively: t(i), t(f(i)), t(f(f(i))), ..., where f(x) = x + lowest_bit(x).